# How get current Activity's name and store it to G class that extends Application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want write dynamically Intent, so I want to write **G.currentActivity** instead of **GSampleActivity.this**.
G class extends Application.

[image]

[image]

I defined G class in application Tag that is before activity Tags:
[image]

Comment: This is so very wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need that... Besides, `G.currentActivity` is null in the shown code

Application class is a Context, so you don't need to store a static field.

Activity class is a Context, so you don't need to grab anything from the Application class.

You can use `GSampleActivity.this` within `startActivity` and keeping around static references to the current Activity is very brittle and asking for bugs and memory leaks.

P.S. Use Android Studio

Comment: The letter G means the Global, and onCreate of Application class run before onCteate of all Activity classes and I define all setting of the program in G classes.
I want to grab from Activity (Activity name) and store it to currentActivity.

Comment: I know when an Application class works, but I don't see why you need to use it the way you've shown. And I'm telling you that you don't need to do that... `GSampleActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName()` will give you the current Activity.

Comment: my purpose is:
Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, ActivitySecond);
"G.currentActivity" be constant every where (every Activity).
G.currentActivity is equel Activity's name (GSampleActivity.this in this example).

Comment: Whatever reason you have for doing that still is not clear. Does your code work? I don't think it should because `G.currentActivity` is 1) never assigned and 2) pointless. You aren't making anything "dynamic" here

Comment: OK, this code not work. if you see the Log.i(...) command, I assigned LOG in G class (in onCreate method) and when I want to use Log.i(String Tag, String msg) I'm writing Log.i(G.LOG, "anything") and this code work correctly although it is pointless, but I don't know, how to assign the currentActivity in G class.

Comment: In other words, in any activity, we must write the name of the activity in the first part of an Intent command. so I want to write a dynamic name (G.currentActivity) everywhere and it assigns activity name in that. G.currentActivity is fixed in any Intent command. I don't know how to assign.

Comment: `G.currentActivity` is not fixed and you never display assign it. And it shouldn't need to be assigned or fixed. You should always start an Intent from the **actual** current Activity, which, in this case is `GSampleActivity.this`